# Problem in using seekg() to read file in C++

Tags: c++, seekg

I am learning to read and write file in C++ and find a problem.

My test.txt file contains 3 string in 3 lines:

```
abc
def
mnp
```

My problem is: I don't understand why I need to use `f.seekg(2, ios::cur);`
instead of `f.seekg(1, ios::cur);`
I know how to use `seekg()` in c++ and I think that I just need to ignore 1 byte
to get the next line by the `getline()` function.

This is my code:

```
ifstream f;
    f.open("D:\\test.txt", ios::in);
    string str1, str2, str3;
    f >> str1;
    f.seekg(2, ios::cur);
    getline(f, str2);
    getline(f, str3);
    cout << str1 << " " << str2 << " " << str3 << endl;
```

Comment: You should not have to seek at all

Comment: Why does the code say `2` then? Where did you get it from? What did the author say about this when you asked them?

Answer (score 1):

Reason for your trouble is explained for example here:
[Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

However about your actual question about `seekg`. You open the file in text mode. This means that when you read the file, line feeds are given to your C++ code as single characters, `'\n'`. But on the disk they may be something else, and it seems you are running your code on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file#Microsoft_Windows_text_files). There newline in a text file is typically two bytes, CR (ASCII code 13) and LF (ASCII code 10). *Reading* or writing in text mode will perform this conversion between a single character in your C++ string vs two bytes in the file for you.

`seekg` works on offsets and does not care about this, offsets are same whether you open the file in text or binary mode. If you use `seekg` to skip new line, your code becomes platform-dependent, on Windows you need to skip 2 bytes as explained above, while in other platforms such as Unix you need to skip just single byte.

So, do not use `seekg` for this purpose, see the linked question for better solutions.

Comment: @babylearnmaths No problem. Note that usual way to say "thank you" here is to upvote the answer. Also, when/if you get a satisfactory answer to your question, it's good to accept the answer you like best (but it's a good idea to wait 24 hours if you want all timezones to have a chance of seeing and answering your question).